# Forwarding Domain but not Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, forwarding

I want to forward the main domain `example.com` to the (WIX webspace) domain `guenterpolt.wixsite.com/example` but not the subdomain `moodle.example.com` which should stay on my server.

I cannot use DNS for this because WIX gives me no IP, so I must use some kind of HTML/PHP or `.htaccess` forwarding. HTML/PHP header or meta refresh forwarding forwards all. Is this possible with `.htacess` and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the subdomain is configured as its own virtual host, then you can use a mod_alias `Redirect` in the main domain's `<VirtualHost>` container:

```
Redirect / https://guenterpolt.wixsite.com/example/
```

I've assumed the target site is HTTPS.

However, if `.htaccess` is your only option (or the two domains are configured in the same VirtualHost), then you can use mod_rewrite instead to redirect just the main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://guenterpolt.wixsite.com/example%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This only applies to the main domain.

This will work in either `.htaccess` or the server config.

Change `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked fine for me, problem solved. I see I must dig deeper into the rewrite condititons in htaccess which is somehow tricky for me as beginner.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the different virtual host file for both websites, i.e one for domain `example.com` and other subdomain `moodle.example.com` in Apache or whatever web server you are using.

Example of apache virtual host file.

File name: `vhost.conf`

```
Listen 80

    <VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
       ServerName dr-polt.at
       DocumentRoot "/www/example1"

       # Other directives here ...
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
       ServerName moodle.dr-polt.at
       DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
       # Other directives here ...

    </VirtualHost>
```

You can either add a `.htaccess` rule in Apache `vhost.conf` or in `.htaccess` file for the required domain in the document root directory.

Comment: Thank you.  As I have no access to vhost.conf I went over to the 2nd solution here mentioned which worked well for me.